# Excel: Conditional formatting with vlookup and value in other cell

Tags: excel, nested, vlookup, conditional-formatting

I want the colour in cells to change depending on the value in another cell.
The complication is I need to first match values in 2 cells, then pick the value next to it, and apply conditional formatting based on this value.

Referring to the image below:
Ex1: Find E2 in Column A, then pick the relevant value in Column C. Use the value in column C to determine Conditional format (i.e. fill E2 with Green, Red, Amber or Grey for Yes, No, Don't Know or Not Relevant respectively).

Ex1: Find G3 in Column A, then pick the relevant value in Column C. Use the value in column C to determine Conditional format (i.e. fill G3 with Green, Red, Amber or Grey for Yes, No, Don't Know or Not Relevant respectively).

I am able to apply conditional formatting based on a single cell value - 4 rules as you can see. But having to create 4 formatting rules for each of 100 cells is tedious

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `INDEX(MATCH())` formula for your conditional format:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($C$2:$C$999,MATCH(E2,$A$2:$A$999,0))="Yes",FALSE)
```

Replace 999 with the last row number of your data. Select the range E2:J38 and create a conditional format with this formula. Repeat this for the other values of column C.